# Give uploaded files an id in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, forms, file

I am developing a website where I have a form and the user can upload multiple images.

`<input  type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" name="files[]" multiple />`

In the UI, I have a radio button on each image and I want the user to select an image from them as the main image. The problem is how can I identify the main image on the backend side ?

I tried to give the images an id's on client side and sent the id of the main image but this didn't work it seems I can't change the file object that is sent.

I am thinking of using getClientOriginalName() is an alternative of the id but I am not sure if that's the best way to do it Also I am not sure if getClientOriginalName() can have duplicate value.

Also I have noticed a field in the file object hashName I wanted to use as an id but it's value was null

[image]